# Dúvida em relação a passagem de parâmetros

Tags: c, funções, parâmetros, recursão

No código a seguir, na linha 5, a função `foo1t` chama a função `foo1` passando dois parâmetros a ela, porém, a função `foo1` tem apenas um parâmetro. É possível acontecer isso ou o código está errado? Se for possível, gostaria de uma explicação.

```
1   int foo1t(int n, int resp) {
2       if (n <= 1) {
3           return resp;
4       } else {
5           return foo1(n-1, n*resp);
6       }
7   }
8
9   int foo1(int n) {
10      return foo1t(n, 1);
11  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não, o código está errado. Provavelmente o passo indutivo deveria ser `return foo1t(n-1, n*resp);`

Funções em C podem ser declaradas "sem parâmetros", e podem ter uma quantidade variável de parâmetros (as funções *variádicas*, como `printf()`), mas se os parâmetros são declarados eles não podem ser chamados com um número errado de parâmetros. No caso de ponteiros ou inteiros, você até pode passar um inteiro no lugar de um ponteiro ou vice-versa, mas o compilador tipicamente vai emitir pelo menos um aviso.